geoclue redhat selinux annoyance
on a clean install of RHEL-8.9 from iso, with selinux in its default state of enforcing, geoclue shows up via sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
SELinux is preventing /usr/libexec/geoclue from search access on the directory /proc/<pid>/cgroup.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that geoclue should be allowed search access on the cgroup directory by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'geoclue' --raw | audit2allow -M my-geoclue
# semodule -X 300 -i my-geoclue.pp

trying to stop this selinux alert with those two commands does not work.

can geoclue be uninstalled?
the geoclue.service shows up as static; can this be disabled to stop the selinux alert from happening?
what is geoclue and why is it there?


tl;dr:
You can try to quickfix like this:
cat << EOF > cust_geoclue.cil
(allow geoclue_t unconfined_service_t (dir (search)))
(allow geoclue_t unconfined_service_t (file (open read)))
EOF
semodule -i cust_geoclue.cil

(tl;dr based on this bug report)
/tl;dr

can geoclue be uninstalled?

You can use dnf to remove the package:
dnf remove geoclue2

If the question is "will things break if I remove it, you can try the command and see what would be uninstalled. (write no when asked to keep the packages)
Fedora Project states it is a D-Bus service that provides location information, so it could be used by another program, probably from the Gnome or KDE suite.

the geoclue.service shows up as static; can this be disabled to stop the selinux alert from happening?

You can disable the service and disable the start at boot with:
systemctl disable --now geoclue.servce

Although it won't prevent other units to start it.
You can prevent this with:
systemctl mask geoclue

Although if a service needs it, it might crash.

what is geoclue and why is it there?

Fedora Project states it is a D-Bus service that provides location information, so it might have been installed as a dependency for another program, probably from the Gnome or KDE suite.

trying to stop this selinux alert with those two commands does not work.

I think this is what you should focus on to solve the annoyance.
With the 2 commands you were advised to do, you should have allow the access and have no more messages.
Unless you allowed one thing, but there is another to add now. (eg. it couldn't access a file, you allowed the access, and now it can access the file but can't write the file)
Could you please run:
ausearch -c 'geoclue' --raw | audit2allow -a

The output will gives us more informations on the denial.
We will have two options:

allow it
remove message about denials if we think it should stays blocked but we don't want to be spammed

We can see together how to fix it, but basically the 2 ways would be those. I put this here just for information but we can dig together.
Remove the messages about it:
# Create a source file with the policies to accept
ausearch -c 'geoclue' --raw | audit2allow -a -m cust_geoclue > cust_geoclue.te
# Replace the verb accept with the "verb" dontaudit
sed -i -e 's/allow/dontaudit/g' cust_geoclue.te
# Compile
checkmodule -M -m -o cust_geoclue.mod cust_geoclue.te
# Compile again
semodule_package -o cust_geoclue.pp -m cust_geoclue.mod
# Install the module
semodule -i cust_geoclue.pp

Allow it:
# 1. Create a source file with the policies to accept
ausearch -c 'geoclue' --raw | audit2allow -a -m cust_geoclue > cust_geoclue.te
# 2. Compile
checkmodule -M -m -o cust_geoclue.mod cust_geoclue.te
# 3. Compile again
semodule_package -o cust_geoclue.pp -m cust_geoclue.mod
# 4. Install the module
semodule -i cust_geoclue.pp
# 5. Check if there are still messages, if so, go to 1 again.

